# The BUTTON with ID of oracle should have 2.5em top margin, solid 1px border, and occupy the available horizontal space

Tags: html, css

please kindly help with the code below, i entered the code but the response is the #oracle button does not have the specified CSS style .. I think am having issue with the occupying the available horizontal space

```
#oracle{margin-top:2.5em; 
    border: 1px solid;
    width:100%
 }

  <button id="oracle" class="mdc-button">Calculate BMI</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your HTML.

Comment: open the console/inspect on your chrome and reload your browser @temmy

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work here: I'd recommend you though to style on class names i.s.o. id's.

```css
#oracle{
    margin-top:2.5em; 
    border: 1px solid;
    width:100%
}
```

```html
<button id="oracle" class="mdc-button">Calculate BMI</button>
```